# Most idiomatic way to write try/catch/finally in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the best way to write the following in Scala? It doesn't look quite right to me - first the forward declaration of the 2 vals, then the long `PrintWriter` creation line, then the`finally`block. The only thing that's idiomatic, is the `catch` block...

```
val outputStream = Try(fs.create(tmpFile))
val writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream.get)))

if (outputStream.isFailure) {
  logger.error(s"Couldn't open file: $tmpFile")
}

try {

  features.foreach {
    case (sectionName, modelRDD) =>
      writer.append("{" + sectionName + ", " + modelRDD.getNumPartitions + "}")
  }

} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    logger.error(s"Got exception", e)
    throw e

} finally {
  outputStream.get.close()
  writer.close()
}
```

Comment: On what basis don't they "look quite right" to you?

Comment: I am new to Scala. Maybe this is all right, but I was hoping for something simpler, as I mentioned: the 2 vals declarations, the writer creation line, and the ```finally``` block. Maybe there is something more idiomatic that I could learn?

Comment: With resources management: http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/usage.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can further use the context of the initial `Try` to execute the complete I/O operation:

First, we define a function that encapsulates our process:

```
def safeFilePrint(tf: => OutputStream)(op: PrintWriter => Unit): Try[Unit] = {
  val os = Try(tf) 
  val write = {
      val writer = os.map(f => new PrintWriter(f))
      val writeOp = writer.map(op)
      val flushOp = writer.map(_.flush)
      writeOp.flatMap(_ => flushOp)
  } 
  val close = os.map(_.close)
  write.flatMap(_ => close)
}
```

And usage:

```
val collection = Seq(...)
val writeResult = safeFilePrint(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/foo.txt"))){w => 
    collection.foreach(elem => w.write(e)
}
```

Note that in contrast with the original code, we have a result of the write operation. Either `writeResult` will be `Success(())` if everything went well or `Failure(exception)` is something went wrong. Based on that our application can further decide what to do.

One may wonder: *"Where is the `finally`?"* In Java, `finally` is used to ensure that some code (typically resource management) would be executed, even in the case that an exception thrown in the `try` scope would cause an exception-handling path to be followed.

In Scala, using constructs like `Try`, `Either` or our own ADT, we lift error handling to the application level. `finally` becomes unnecessary as our program is able to deal with the failure as just another valid state of the program.

Comment: Is `Try` lazy? That `close` operation seems sequenced wrong otherwise

Comment: I guess I'm just not Scala-savy enough. It looks like `_.close` could run before `op`. Why use `flatMap` with a constant function? Shouldn't it rather be something like `os.map(new PrintWriter(_)).map(op).flatMap(_=> os.map(_.close))`?

Comment: @Bergi `Try` is eager. The value of `write` will be computed before the value of `close`. That compact expression is tempting, but If we do that and `op` fails with an `Exception`, do we ever execute `close` ? I don't think that way preserves the semantics of `finally` in the original question.  I use `flatmap` at the end to combine the results of `close` and `write`, so the process is a `Success` only if both are a `Success`.

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't consider `op` to fail since it uses `map` not `flatMap`. Btw, I think `.flatMap(_ => close)` could be `.orElse(close)`

Comment: @Bergi `write.orElse(close)` will be `Success(())` if `write` fails and `close` succeeds (e.g. read-only file). I would like the operation to succeed only if all steps succeed. (tricky function, isn't it? I re-wrote it many times while trying to answer. I'm still not sure whether the by-name parameter is the best way to pass the stream creation function)

Comment: Oh, right; I'm tired. I'd love to have some `Try.both(write, close)`…

Comment: @maasg - as written, I get the impression that ```close``` will be executed *if and only if* the whole flow succeeds. But I would want to call ```close``` even if an exception was thrown in the ```foreach```, i.e. after the stream was open, during writing to the stream. In other words, it seems to me that the semantics of the original ```finally``` are independent of the success/failure state of the operations on the stream after it is open.

Comment: Whatever value you return from ```safeFilePrint``` you *must* recover the stream resource.

Comment: @frank what makes you think that the `finally` semantics are not preserved?

Comment: @Frank here's a notebook using the function. See how the stream is closed in all relevant cases. (I did notice that the function needs a `flush` to properly write)  https://gist.github.com/maasg/dc9712eb6221be536e93f1927ddacd9c

Comment: @maasg - so the documentation for ```Try.flatMap``` reads: ```Returns the given function applied to the value from this `Success` or returns this if this is a `Failure`.```. I thought that meant that in case of ```Failure```, ```close``` would not be executed.

Comment: @maasg - and sure enough, the code for ```Try.flatMap``` reads: ```def flatMap[U](f: T => Try[U]): Try[U] = this.asInstanceOf[Try[U]]```. I can see that in your notebook, it does work though. So why does it work??? There is something I am missing.

Comment: @Frank What you're confusing is that `write` and `close` are values already evaluated, like "Success(())". When we reach the `flatMap`, the effects have already taken place. The `flatMap` is used to compute the final result of the operation so that the operation is a `Success` if `write` is `Success` and `close` is Success.

Comment: @maasg - got it - I was playing it and got to the same conclusion :-) Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: @maasg - for extra credit, is this function easier to formally prove for correctness? I've always eyed formal proof to replace unit testing, and now that I have a chance to do FP stuff, could I reap the additional benefit that I would not need to write unit tests anymore??

Comment: @Frank this is an impure function doing I/O without making it explicit. I don't think we can easily prove correctness. Using substitution we could prove the success and failure states, but say nothing whether our Bytes were actually written, which is -at the end- the actual goal of the function. Will need to dive in `M[IO]` for something more functional.

Answer (score 3):

Finally settled on that code after reading @maasg's answer, which highlights the monadic flow and is more "symmetric". It looks much, much better than the code in the OP!

```
def safePrintToStream(gen: => OutputStream)(op: PrintWriter => Unit): Try[Unit] = {
  val os = Try(gen)
  val writer = os.map(stream => new PrintWriter(stream))
  val write = writer.map(op(_))
  val flush = writer.map(_.flush)
  val close = os.map(_.close)
  write.flatMap(_ => flush).flatMap(_ => close)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `flush` and `close` be lazy in this code?